# Merge tag request: 13 different groups about [file*] tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Merge tags:

- [file-association](/questions/tagged/file-association) x 123 (Target)

  [fileassociation](/questions/tagged/fileassociation) x 18
- [file-comparison](/questions/tagged/file-comparison) x 31 (Target)

  [file-compare](/questions/tagged/file-compare) x 18
- [file-download](/questions/tagged/file-download) x 1310

  [file-downloads](/questions/tagged/file-downloads) x 24 (Target)
- [filegroup](/questions/tagged/filegroup) x 24 (Target) [file-groups]

  [filegroups](/questions/tagged/filegroups) x 4
- [filehandle](/questions/tagged/filehandle) x 145

  [file-handles](/questions/tagged/file-handles) x 7 (Target)
- [file-management](/questions/tagged/file-management) x 99 (Target)

  [filemanagement](/questions/tagged/filemanagement) x 15
- [file-manager](/questions/tagged/file-manager) x 11 (Target)

  [filemanager](/questions/tagged/filemanager) x 59
- [file-permissions](/questions/tagged/file-permissions) x 602 (Target)

  [filepermissions](/questions/tagged/filepermissions) x 19
- [file-parsing](/questions/tagged/file-parsing) x 11 (Target)

  [fileparsing](/questions/tagged/fileparsing) x 35
- [file-path](/questions/tagged/file-path) x 23 (Target)

  [filepath](/questions/tagged/filepath) x 373
- [filesystems](/questions/tagged/filesystems) x 2702

  [file-system](/questions/tagged/file-system) x 157 (Target) [file-systems]
- [file-size](/questions/tagged/file-size) x 49 (Target)

  [filesize](/questions/tagged/filesize) x 325
- [file-time](/questions/tagged/file-time) x 4 (Target)

  [filetime](/questions/tagged/filetime) x 25

Out of these groups only one tag in group should be present. Merge each group into one tag (Target) and give others as synonyms. Some tags (Target) needs to be renamed after merging. If anyone suggesting more file tags to be merged please notify in comments on question. If anything wrong with these tags, please give responses.

Comment: Is there any chance of any of the tags referring to a class/package/etc. in some language?

Comment: @nhahtdh: I am doubt about [file-compare] and [filepath] but not sure. And for rest of tags, I don't think so.

Answer (score 4):

**Killed:**

- [file-time](/questions/tagged/file-time)
- [filepermissions](/questions/tagged/filepermissions)
- [fileassociation](/questions/tagged/fileassociation)
- [file-associations](/questions/tagged/file-associations)
- [filegroups](/questions/tagged/filegroups)
- [filemanagement](/questions/tagged/filemanagement)
- [file-downloads](/questions/tagged/file-downloads)
- [large-file-download](/questions/tagged/large-file-download)

Someone else killed [file-compare](/questions/tagged/file-compare) off.